# $(shell …) command in Makefile is not executed correctly, but works in bash/sh

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I want to count the number of nodes in a graphviz file in a Makefile to use it to start a process for each node.
When I run

```
grep -- -\> graph.gv | while read line; do for w in $line; do echo $w; done; done | grep [Aa-Zz] | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

in the shell, it prints the number of nodes as expected.
However, when I use it in my Makefile

```
NODES := $(shell grep -- -\> graph.gv | while read line; do for w in $line; do echo $w; done; done | grep [Aa-Zz] | sort | uniq | wc -l)
```

`${NODES}` is always 0.

Comment: `[Aa-Zz]` almost certainly won't be what you want. That means `A`, `a` to `Z`, or `z`. It doesn't mean `Aa` to `Zz`. Also, `[` is a shell metacharacter too, so unless you quote it, it may get expanded if you've got single-letter filenames in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `$` sign.  Say:

```
NODES := $(shell grep -- -\> graph.gv | while read line; do for w in $$line; do echo $$w; done; done | grep [Aa-Zz] | sort | uniq | wc -l)
```